# Are there any synonymous alternatives to the prefix "exo"?

Tags: synonyms, prefixes

I'm specifically looking for another prefix that has the same or a similar meaning to "exo".

Comment: Why? Details are helpful; so is explaining the research that you have done so far.

Comment: What do you think "exo" means?  What synonyms have you found thus far (you have looked, right?) and why did they not suit your needs?

Comment: I'm not sure what research I can actually do. Google is complete and infuriating garbage, and I have few if any other resources. I'm just asking if anyone knows of something like this offhand. After some thought, I think "tele" is used in a vaguely similar way, though it's not exactly suitable. The reason why I'd like to use another term is simply that the term exo is overused and often associated with technology or insects, and I wanted a slightly less used term that would allow me to avoid those associations.

Comment: You really need to include more context in your question, as well as a sample sentence showing how you would use it.  (Put an X or ___ where the prefix would go.)  You might also want to take [the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read more about how to [ask good questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, what do I think "exo" means? what kind of question is that?

Comment: No, I don't need to include more information. My question is concise. Are there any other prefixes with the same meaning as exo. if you know what exo means and what a prefix is, then you should have no problem understanding the question.

Comment: Rather, I don't *see the need to include more information. I'm not trying to be rude, but people on stack exchange tend to be very nitpicky and often rude in their own way, and that makes participating here very tiresome after a while.

Comment: @SebastianHahn I sympathize with you, but not with the way you're handling yourself in the comments. When you walk into someone's house, you don't start telling them "this is the way **I** do things, don't tell me different". We have rules here, and believe it or not, those rules *serve a purpose*, and we're asking you to abide by them. It is you, after all, who are asking us for help.

Comment: See, the thing is, this isn't your house. This is a public use website. And I haven't broken any rules. I've found that It doesn't matter if I'm asking or answering questions. A majority of the people on the stack exchange network are uptight, rude expletives, who are always looking to find faults were there are none.

Comment: There are various lists of English prefixes, together with the meanings they add, available on the internet. [Englishhints.com](http://www.englishhints.com/list-of-prefixes.html) is a typical example; you can look for matches. Even showing (a) the meaning/s _exo_ carries and (b) a link like this with 'I found no matches here' would validate the question. Though there may _be_ no synonyms.

Comment: Honestly, it hadn't occurred to me that there were so few prefixes in the English language that it would be practical to search through a list of them. Apparently (if the list you linked is exhaustive) there are less than 70... TIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that ***exo-*** has the following definition:

> ***[exo-](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exo-)***
>
> PREFIX
>
> External; from outside.
>   *‘exodermis’*

I would go with either ***extra-***:

> ***[extra-](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extra-)***
>
> PREFIX
>
> 1. Outside; beyond.
>      *‘extracellular’*
>      *‘extraterritorial’*
>
> 1.1 Beyond the scope of.
>   *‘extracurricular’*

or ***outer***:

> ***[outer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outer)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. attributive Outside; external.
>      *‘the outer layer of the skin’*
>      *‘the outer door’*

I will note that **outer** is an *adjective* rather than a *prefix*.

Comment: I hadn't even considered extra. Very good answer. thank you.